# Update panel affects menu element

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using asp.net, webforms.
I have a real time clock, some images and a menu. For updating the clock I use an UpdatePanel, that is triggered by a timer Tick event. The problem is that the menu is also affected even it is not part of the UpdatePanel. More exactly, the sub-menu isn't working, therefore I can't acces any root's children.

```
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrClock" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgPub1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/UPT.png" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgPub2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/UPT1.png" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblClock" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div>
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#7C6F57" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
                <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Acasa" Value="Acasa"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Manipulare Date" Value="Manipulare Date">
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" Text="Actualizare Date" Value="Actualizare Date"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Adaugare Angajati" Value="Adaugare Angajati"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Stergere Angajati" Value="Stergere Angajati"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="Tiparire" Value="Tiparire">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Stat de Plata" Value="Stat de Plata"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Fluturasi" Value="Fluturasi"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Modificare Procente" Value="Modificare Procente"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
                <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
                <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
```

Here is the OnTick code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lblClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        imgPub1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/UPT.png";
        imgPub2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/UPT1.png";
    }
}

protected void tmrClock_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rndNum = rnd.Next(0, 2);
    if (rndNum == 0)
    {
        imgPub1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/UPT.png";
        imgPub2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/UPT1.png";
    }
    else
    {
        imgPub1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/UPT1.png";
        imgPub2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/UPT.png";
    }
    lblClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

Comment: Cannot replicate with the markup you've provided. Maybe you want to share the code of the `OnTick` event handler?

Comment: Thank you for the update. Nevertheless, I still cannot emulate the problem. Everything works fine with your example. See for yourself (I've used two random country flags as images): https://i.imgur.com/O1KcS0m.gif

Comment: @dpant Thanks for trying the code, it's very strange, I have tried several browsers but the menu is still not working. It might be a config or a .NET problem on my side.